# Windows - Windows have thick pink and blue border

Tags: windows, windows-10

Somehow my parent's windows 10 laptop now has thick pink and blue borders around every window. How can these be reset to the default (thin and white I think)?
 Theme and color settings in the settings app are normal and default. Not pink color selected.

[image: Screenshot of the issue]

Comment: It looks like somebody changed the theme / color scheme but I'm confused: Someone with your professional experience would have checked that already?

Comment: I did check that but everything is normal.

Comment: First thing you need to understand when asking: We aren't seeing what you're seeing and unless you provide such information we know nothing about the PC. That said, what exactly do you mean by *everything is normal*? Anything you can change on how it looks is normal. Now, if there's a mismatch between what is selected and what it actually shows, that's not normal.

Comment: Now please read the answer below and if that doesn't apply to your case (unlikely), [edit] the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

(answer been **edited**) 
If I really understand your question there were some change made in your **WINDOWS appearance**. In order to return the **screen** to how it was:
1.Right click on **desktop**  it wit show you this screen :

[image].

2. It will show you the following screen [image], in this screen you will see the options for the display and appearance. Click the color tab.
3. Lastly you will see this [image] , here's what probably made the pink color being selected as the default windows color.  There's an option in the bottom - Automatically pick an accent color from my background - here you have two checkbox the first -start,taskbar,and action center **simply** uncheck this one.